# Markup error on some tags in a structure generated inside a loop

Tags: php, xml, markup

I'm having a problem, better said a bug, in an XML structure generated in a while loop with PHP.

This is the PHP code that I use to access my DB and generate an XML with the retrieved information (also, I define the content-type as text/xml before):

```
<?php include("basededatos.php"); $query = mysql_query("SELECT tipo,nombre,direccion,telefono,dias_habiles,sabados,domingos,coordenadas FROM iglesias"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) : ?>
<iglesia cords="<?php echo $row["coordenadas"]; ?>" tipo="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["tipo"]); ?>">
    <nombre><?php echo utf8_encode($row["nombre"]); ?></nombre>
    <direccion><?php if($row["direccion"]==""){echo "Dirección no especificada";} else {echo utf8_encode($row["direccion"]);} ?></direccion>
    <telefono><?php if($row["telefono"]==""){echo "Teléfono no especificado";} else {echo utf8_encode($row["telefono"]);} ?></telefono>
    <horarios>
        <dias_habiles><?php if($row["dias_habiles"]==""){echo "Sin información";} else {echo utf8_encode($row["dias_habiles"]);} ?></dias_habiles>
        <sabados><?php if($row["sabados"]==""){echo "Sin información";} else {echo utf8_encode($row["sabados"]);} ?></sabados>
        <domingos><?php if($row["domingos"]==""){echo "Sin información";} else {echo utf8_encode($row["domingos"]);} ?></domingos>
    </horarios>
</iglesia>
```

Good, now, thanks to that I obtain a big XML, more than 2500 lines thanks to 255 rows that I have in my DB but sometimes I have a weird error in only one tag, like this last one:

```
<iglesia cords="-34.59915445189461, -58.39169159531593" tipo="Parroquia">
<nombre>Parroquia Nuestra Señora del Carmen</nombre>
<direccion>Rodriguez Peña 840</direccion>
<telefono>011 4816 3511</telefono>
<horarios>
    <dias_habiles>8:00, 11:30, 19:30</dias_habiles>
    <sabados>8:00, 17:30, 19:00</sabados>
    <domingos>8:30, 11:00, 12:15, 17:30, 19:00, 20:15</domingos>
</horarios>
</iglesia>
<iglesia cords="-34.595964052770476, -58.40230107307434" tipo="Parroquia">
<nombre>Parroquia Nuestra Señora del Carmelo</nombre>
<direccion>Marcelo T. de Alvear 2465</direccion>
<telefono>011 4821 5954</telefono>
<horarios>
    //Look here, the next line
    dias_habiles>8:00, 11:00, 19:00, 20:00</dias_habiles>
    <sabados>8:00, 11:00, 19:00, 20:00</sabados>
    <domingos>8:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 19:00, 20:00, 21:00</domingos>
</horarios>
</iglesia>
```

As you can see the < is missing in the dias_habiles tag, but the one dias_habiles before that is correct, and after that error all the dias_habiles are well marked.

Also, is not always the problem with this tag, it's just an example, it can happens with any random tag, only once and without propagation, in the XML. Why? How?

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes...
Replace all data from DB like

```
<?php echo utf8_encode($row["nombre"]); ?>
```

with control text such as:

```
<?php echo "Control text"; ?>
```

See if the problem goes away - if so then you can be sure the issue is connected to the format of the 'data' coming from the db. you may need to apply string formatting functions to the text that you are grabbing from the DB. Some sanitizing subroutinte etc.

If the problem doesnt go away - then its obviously an issue with the rest. Either way your headache is halved.